# How to stop music player stop one removed from recents?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have been using this code which i got from stackoverflow to  notification dismissible when playing music in background like in Spotify and Google Music. But now its causing a bug, when playing a song on my app and if we remove it from recents i.e., from foreground and background the music keeps playing unlike spotify or youtube music which stops playing the music once removed from recents.
Can anyone help me with this please..
Here is the code :

```
abstract class InvincibleService : Service() {
    protected val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    protected abstract val isInvincibilityEnabled: Boolean

    protected abstract val notificationId: Int

    private var invincibility: Invincibility? = null

    private val isAllowedToStartForegroundServices: Boolean
        get() = !isAtLeastAndroid12 || isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): Binder? {
        invincibility?.stop()
        invincibility = null
        return null
    }

    override fun onRebind(intent: Intent?) {
        invincibility?.stop()
        invincibility = null
        super.onRebind(intent)
    }

    override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        if (isInvincibilityEnabled && isAllowedToStartForegroundServices) {
            invincibility = Invincibility()
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        invincibility?.stop()
        invincibility = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    protected fun makeInvincible(isInvincible: Boolean = true) {
        if (isInvincible) {
            invincibility?.start()
        } else {
            invincibility?.stop()
        }
    }

    protected abstract fun shouldBeInvincible(): Boolean

    protected abstract fun notification(): Notification?

    private inner class Invincibility : BroadcastReceiver(), Runnable {
        private var isStarted = false
        private val intervalMs = 30_000L

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            when (intent?.action) {
                Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON -> handler.post(this)
                Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF -> notification()?.let { notification ->
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this)
                    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
                }
            }
        }

        @Synchronized
        fun start() {
            if (!isStarted) {
                isStarted = true
                handler.postDelayed(this, intervalMs)
                registerReceiver(this, IntentFilter().apply {
                    addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
                    addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
                })
            }
        }

        @Synchronized
        fun stop() {
            if (isStarted) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this)
                unregisterReceiver(this)
                isStarted = false
            }
        }

        override fun run() {
            if (shouldBeInvincible() && isAllowedToStartForegroundServices) {
                notification()?.let { notification ->
                    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
                    stopForeground(false)
                    handler.postDelayed(this, intervalMs)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want that once the app is removed from recents(Background) it should stop the music player as well.

Comment: Call stop music code when foreground service is destroyed.